# Oracle - update , decode and set value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table e.g.

```
**Fruit   Number**
Apple     5
Grape     9
Orange    1
Coconut   54
Mango     22
```

I want to :

1. Select the whole list
2. Put 'Apple, Mango,Coconut' at top of the list.
3. Update the current order, where number = rownum

The list should look as follows :

```
**Fruit   Number**
Apple     1
Mango     2
Coconut   3
Grape     4
Orange    5
```

I tried the following however getting syntax issues ..

```
update tablename 
set id = rownum
where fruit in (select fruit from table order by decode(fruit,'Apple',1,'Mango',2,'Coconut',3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT ROWNUM+5 AS r, fruit, number FROM TABLE
    WHERE fruit NOT IN ('Apple', 'Mango', 'Coconut', 'Grape', 'Orange')
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS r, 'Apple' AS fruit, number FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS r, 'Mango' AS fruit, number FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS r, 'Coconut' AS fruit, number FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS r, 'Grape' AS fruit, number FROM TABLE
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS r, 'Orange' AS fruit, number FROM TABLE
) 
SET number = r;
```

Comment: Thanks however there are a lot more 'fruits' in the table. How can i set those to a generic value?. So the code sorts out the first 5, but after the first 5 , how can i set the number = rowid?

Comment: Thats not really what i'm looking for. Is there a way to incorporate it into the else statement? e.g. Else number = rownum (tried this but i get syntax error)

Comment: Oh, now I understand, gimme a sec

Answer (score 0):

Following query will do that for you.

```
UPDATE table SET number =
CASE fruit
    WHEN 'Apple' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Mango' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Coconut' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Grape' THEN 4
    WHEN 'Orange' THEN 5
END;
```